# Vehicle Spawn in Race with Traffic: Off

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

We tried to find a way to end a GTA race that involved a jump between two floating platforms that was impossible with our race vehicles (lawnmower). There were obviously no moving cars as well as parked cars, no planes or choppers on the Sandy Shores airfield, no boats and even no trains. Trying to enter a garage or calling any service (mechanic, Merryweather, Pegasus, 911) was not successful.

**Are there any loopholes to use when playing a (GTA) race with Traffic set to Off?**

Comment: What stopped you from restarting the job?

Comment: @Mano Nothing, I just want to know if there are any loopholes for reference

Answer (score 2):

Sadly without glitching or changing settings that would be impossible... if the race is in GTA mode you may be able to use a parachute or explosives to help.